# Gradle project sync failure - no error message

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**I know that this title has been used before, but I can't find any clue as to the reason for the failure!**

"Messages" "Event Log" "Gradle Console" don't show any thing, I can't make any sense of "Log in Explorer"...  so I will display my "build.gradle" files.

I recently updated to

- Android Studio 2.1
- Android SDK tools 25.1.6 and
- Android Platform N revision 2
- Gradle 2.13

app\build.gradle:

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'base'
> 
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
>     buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.hackaton.academy.android.walkup"
>         minSdkVersion 15
>         targetSdkVersion 'N'
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.3'
>     compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.3'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.3'
>     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
>     compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
>     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson'}
```

project\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking a look!! (I have been working two days on this)

Comment: are you installed android-N api from android SDK Manager

Comment: N Preview revision 2

Comment: Android N Preview revision 2

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't make any sense of "Log in Explorer" '? Do you mean you cannot open the log? Clicking the option should bring you to the folder with the idea.log file, a text file describing the last actions taken by Android Studio, with any problems encountered. Do you mean that you can't make any sense of the stuff you find in the log? If it is the latter, you need to show some contents here. There should be an error recorded somewhere towards the end of the file. In my case I found the problem among several long stack traces recorded there.